# Navision 2015 - Upload excel file to salary journal

Tags: web-services, excel-interop, microsoft-dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2015

I'm doing a integration from a third party system with Nav 2015, I need to export a excelsheet to Nav 2015. I know the nav format and excel sheet has been formatted the same way. We can do it via GUI but we have to automate it via web service or something. How to do it? (I can use excel interops to generate excelsheets)

Comment: Yes. Web service. Use it.

Comment: @MakSim couldn't find any links on the topic, have you got any?

Comment: Sure. Here is a place to start. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd339004.aspx

Comment: Basically each integration possibility in Nav will require you to develop something in Nav. Either publish web service or set a job batch to monitor files in certain folder.